# Generate and handle 3 billion elements matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, combinations, large-data

I need to generate the complete set of combinations obtained when choosing any 8 numbers from a vector of 25 elements. This can be done by using the [Combinator](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24325-combinator-combinations-and-permutations) function but is very slow for very large matrix and is becoming RAM consuming. Can anyone suggest a clever way to generate this?

Example: using "sample 3 from vector of 4" would yield the following result (`H=3` and `L=4`):

```
1 1 1
1 1 2
1 1 3
1 1 4
1 2 2
1 2 3
1 2 4
1 3 3
1 3 4
1 4 4
2 2 2
2 2 3
2 2 4
2 3 3
2 3 4
2 4 4
3 3 3
3 3 4
3 4 4
4 4 4
```

The following code is what I am using now to generate the matrix.

```
livello = 10:10:250;
H = 5;
L = length(livello);
a = combnk(1:H+L-1, H);
b = cumsum([a(:,1)  diff(a,[],2) - 1],2);
PianoSperimentale = livello(b);
```

Unfortunately, with more complex cases such as `L=74`, `H=8` and `livello = 10:10:750` the elements number of the `PianoSperimentale` matrix rise quickly following the expression `(L+H-1)!/(H!(L-1)!)`. As said before, the elements of the `PianoSperimentale` are roughly 3*10^10. Is there any clever way to generate and handle this huge matrix other than buy a computer with 256Gb of Ram :)?

#### EDIT: Complete Code

```
clear; close all; clc;

s = RandStream('mt19937ar','Seed',1); RandStream.setGlobalStream(s);

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%                       VARIABLES DECLARATION                           %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

H = 5;

lover_bound = 10; upper_bound = 250; steps = 20;
livello = lover_bound:steps:upper_bound;

PesoTarget = 250;
LimiteInferiore = PesoTarget - 9;

IncertezzaCella = 0.5 * 10^(-6);

%SIMULATIONS VARIABLES
Alfa = 0.123;
NumeroProve = 3000;

% OBJECTIVE FUNCTION COST COEFFICIENTS
C_u = 0.03; c_p = 0.6; c_f = 734; c_l = 3.2;


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%                         GENERATE SOLUTIONS                            %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

L = length(livello); livello = sort(livello,'descend');

a = combnk(1:H+L-1, H);
b = cumsum([a(:,1)  diff(a,[],2) - 1],2);
PianoSperimentale = livello(b);
NumeroEsperimenti = size(PianoSperimentale,1);

MatriceCombinazioni = combn([0 1],H);

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%                          ADD UNCERTAINTY                              %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

PesoCestelli = randn(NumeroEsperimenti,H)*Alfa;
PesoCestelli = (1+PesoCestelli).*PianoSperimentale;
idx = PesoCestelli<0;
random = randn(sum(idx(:)), 1);
PesoCestelli(idx) = random.*((1+Alfa).*PianoSperimentale(idx));

%ADD ERROR (ERROR = IncertezzaCella)
Incertezza = randn(NumeroEsperimenti,H)*IncertezzaCella;
PesoIncertezza = abs((1+Incertezza).*PesoCestelli);

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%                             SIMULATION                                %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


for i = 1:NumeroProve
    W = PesoCestelli * MatriceCombinazioni';
    W_Inc = PesoIncertezza * MatriceCombinazioni';
    
    [~,comb] = min(abs(W_Inc-PesoTarget),[],2);
    
    W_migl = W(sub2ind(size(W),1:size(W,1),comb'))';
    
    W_tot_migl(:,i) = W_migl;
    
    
    PesoCestelli_2 = randn(NumeroEsperimenti,H)*Alfa;
    PesoCestelli_2 = (1+PesoCestelli_2).*PianoSperimentale;
    idx = PesoCestelli_2<0;
    random = randn(sum(idx(:)), 1);
    PesoCestelli_2(idx) = random.*((1+Alfa).*PianoSperimentale(idx));
    
    %ADD ERROR (ERROR = IncertezzaCella)
    Incertezza = randn(NumeroEsperimenti,H)*IncertezzaCella;
    PesoIncertezza_2 = abs((1+Incertezza).*PesoCestelli_2);
    
    
    PesoCestelli(MatriceCombinazioni(comb,:)~=0) = ...
        PesoCestelli_2(MatriceCombinazioni(comb,:)~=0); 
    PesoIncertezza(MatriceCombinazioni(comb,:)~=0) = ...
        PesoIncertezza_2(MatriceCombinazioni(comb,:)~=0); 
    
    clear PesoIncertezza2
end

n_b = sum(logical(W_tot_migl>=LimiteInferiore),2);

Media_b = sum(W_tot_migl.*(W_tot_migl>LimiteInferiore),2)./...
    sum(W_tot_migl>LimiteInferiore,2);
ValoreFunzioneObiettivo = C_u .* Media_b + (NumeroProve./n_b) .* c_p + ...
    (c_f./n_b) + ((NumeroProve - n_b)./n_b) .* c_l;
```

The output is `ObjectiveFunctionValue`, mean and stddev of `W_tot_migl` and the `PianoSperimentale` row that gave the minimum of `ObjectiveFunctionValue`.

Comment: Why do you need to have all the data in your RAM memory simultaneously?

Comment: @VictorMay because the computer of my department can store on the HDD ~5Gb per user.

Comment: I'll rephrase my question: why do you need to store all this data simultaneously at all?

Comment: It's a part of a BruteForce approach to solve a problem. I need to explore all possibile solutions in order to establish patterns

Comment: ... and brute force is the only way?

Comment: Why not compute each solution at the time you need to access it?

Comment: Perhaps it will be easier to help if you post the code that you intend to run on your data.

Comment: I do not know any other method to evaluate every single solution. The problema is already been solved via GA, PSO, SPSA and RSM but, in order to study a particular behaviour I need to evaluate and judge all solutions. @VictorMay Compute each solution one at the time will be nice even  think that the performances will be lower. Give me some time to clean it and i'll post it here.

Comment: If the order in which you access the data elements is known before hand, or the access pattern follows a locality principle, you can use caching to improve the runtime over computing each solution one at a time.

Comment: I do not need to know the "access" order, the algorithm can take and evaluate any solutions. I just need to know what solutions gave me the best objective function value. 

I edited my first post including the whole code.

Comment: As @VictorMay said, you probably don't need all those combinations in memory at the same time. Would it be ok for you to have a loop that generates one a time?

Comment: @LuisMendo yes but, since the problems is time consuming I'd like a performance solutions...I don't know, maybe create a small portions of that matrix and send those portions to each worker and iterate this process...Is it doable?

Comment: If you want performance, you shouldn't be working with Matlab.

Comment: @VictorMay If performance is your _main_ concern you shouldn't be working with Matlab. But you may want to work in Matlab for other reasons, and still want the best performance that can be achieved within Matlab

Comment: If you want to iterate over 3 billion elements with a relatively simple logic that doesn't require Matlab's toolboxes, performance should be your main concern.

Comment: I need to use Matlab for compatibility (with others). As I said before, will be nice have a solution that generate `n` portions of `PianoSperimentale` matrix and deliver each portion to each available worker. I think that using this approach I can be quite fast...but unfortunately I do not know if it is possible and how can I do that...

Comment: If you have the Matlab parallel computing toolbox, you can do that using the parfor (stands for parallel for) loop statement. Basically, all  you need to do is to call "matlabpool open" in order to initialize the parallel computing environment, and replace your for loop with a parfor loop. This, assuming that every iteration's computations are independent of all previous iterations.

Comment: @VictorMay for 1Milion matrix, Vectorized approach is way faster than using parfor (on 12 core machine). I don't know how to create portions of that matrix...I'm able to create the all matrix and than slice it in parts but i don't have enough ram to store it so I need to create portions.

Comment: @LuisMendo any thoughts about how to generate portions of that matrix at each iteration?

Comment: @gmeroni Perhaps use nested loops, but vectorize as many innermost loops as memory allows