# Optimize matrices operations

Tags: arrays, matlab, optimization, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I'm optimizing via Genetic Algorithm a machine simulator (of a MultiheadWeigher machine) in order to solve the well known "Setup problem". I based all the code on matricies but with the [multiproduct case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24259125/complete-set-of-combinations-combining-3-set) I think there is still some inefficiency...

#### Code

```
function [f] = MHW(position_matrix, HA, HB, HC)

global W_best_tot
global Function
global n_b_global

nComb = size(position_matrix,1);
dim = size(position_matrix,2);

WL = 241;

%SIMULATIONS VARIABLES
alpha = 0.123;
nSim = 3000;
CellUncertainty = 0.5 * 10^(-6);

%// Define Product Hopper allocation
WT_A = 130; WL_A = 129;
WT_B = 30; WL_B = 29;
%HC = 2; 
WT_C = 90; WL_C = 89;

%// COMBINATION MATRIX

CombinantionMatrix_A = combn([0 1], HA);
CombinantionMatrix_B = combn([0 1], HB);
CombinantionMatrix_C = combn([0 1], HC);

if HA == 1
    CombinantionMatrix_A = CombinantionMatrix_A.';
end
if HB == 1
    CombinantionMatrix_B = CombinantionMatrix_B.';
end
if HC == 1
    CombinantionMatrix_C = CombinantionMatrix_C.';
end

CombinantionMatrix_A_Transp = CombinantionMatrix_A.';
CombinantionMatrix_B_Transp = CombinantionMatrix_B.';
CombinantionMatrix_C_Transp = CombinantionMatrix_C.';

% OBJECTIVE FUNCTION COST COEFFICIENTS
Cu_A = 0.03; c_p = 0.6; c_f = 734; c_l = 3.2;
Cu_B = 0.09;
Cu_C = 0.04;

[HopperWeight UncertainWeight] = Weight(nComb, dim, alpha, ...
    position_matrix, CellUncertainty);

HopperWeight_A = HopperWeight(:,1:HA);
HopperWeight_B = HopperWeight(:,HA+1:HA+HB);
HopperWeight_C = HopperWeight(:,HA+HB+1:HA+HB+HC);

UncertainWeight_A = UncertainWeight(:,1:HA);
UncertainWeight_B = UncertainWeight(:,HA+1:HA+HB);
UncertainWeight_C = UncertainWeight(:,HA+HB+1:HA+HB+HC);

W_best_tot = zeros(nComb, nSim);
W_best_ABC = zeros(nComb, 3, nSim);

for ii=1:nSim

    W_A = HopperWeight_A * CombinantionMatrix_A_Transp;
    W_B = HopperWeight_B * CombinantionMatrix_B_Transp;
    W_C = HopperWeight_C * CombinantionMatrix_C_Transp;

    W_Unc_A = UncertainWeight_A * CombinantionMatrix_A_Transp;
    W_Unc_B = UncertainWeight_B * CombinantionMatrix_B_Transp;
    W_Unc_C = UncertainWeight_C * CombinantionMatrix_C_Transp;

    [~,comb_A] = min(abs(W_Unc_A - WT_A),[],2);
    [~,comb_B] = min(abs(W_Unc_B - WT_B),[],2);
    [~,comb_C] = min(abs(W_Unc_C - WT_C),[],2);

    W_best_A = W_A(sub2ind_mod(size(W_A),1:size(W_A,1),comb_A.')).';
    W_best_B = W_B(sub2ind_mod(size(W_B),1:size(W_B,1),comb_B.')).';
    W_best_C = W_C(sub2ind_mod(size(W_C),1:size(W_C,1),comb_C.')).';

    W_best_ABC(:,:,ii) = [W_best_A W_best_B W_best_C];
    W_best_tot(:,ii) = sum(W_best_ABC(:,:,ii),2);

    [HopperWeight_2_A UncertainWeight_2_A] = Weight(nComb, HA, alpha, ...
        position_matrix(:,1:HA), CellUncertainty);
    [HopperWeight_2_B UncertainWeight_2_B] = Weight(nComb, HB, alpha, ...
        position_matrix(:,HA+1:HA+HB), CellUncertainty);
    [HopperWeight_2_C UncertainWeight_2_C] = Weight(nComb, HC, alpha, ...
        position_matrix(:,HA+HB+1:HA+HB+HC), CellUncertainty);

    idx = CombinantionMatrix_A(comb_A,:)~=0;
    HopperWeight_A(idx) = HopperWeight_2_A(idx);
    UncertainWeight_A(idx) = UncertainWeight_2_A(idx);
    idx = CombinantionMatrix_B(comb_B,:)~=0;
    HopperWeight_B(idx) = HopperWeight_2_B(idx);
    UncertainWeight_B(idx) = UncertainWeight_2_B(idx);
    idx = CombinantionMatrix_C(comb_C,:)~=0;
    HopperWeight_C(idx) = HopperWeight_2_C(idx);
    UncertainWeight_C(idx) = UncertainWeight_2_C(idx);

    clear HopperWeight_2_A HopperWeight_2_B HopperWeight_2_C ...
        UncertainWeight_2_A UncertainWeight_2_B UncertainWeight_2_C;

end


n_b = logical(W_best_tot >= WL);
n_bA = logical(reshape(W_best_ABC(:,1,:), nComb, nSim) >= WL_A);
n_bB = logical(reshape(W_best_ABC(:,2,:), nComb, nSim) >= WL_B);
n_bC = logical(reshape(W_best_ABC(:,3,:), nComb, nSim) >= WL_C);

n_b_global = sum(n_b .* n_bA .* n_bB .* n_bC, 2);

GAvg_A  = sum(reshape(W_best_ABC(:,1,:), nComb, nSim).*(reshape(...
            W_best_ABC(:,1,:), nComb, nSim) > WT_A),2)./sum(reshape(...
            W_best_ABC(:,1,:), nComb, nSim) > WT_A,2);
GAvg_B  = sum(reshape(W_best_ABC(:,2,:), nComb, nSim).*(reshape(...
            W_best_ABC(:,2,:), nComb, nSim) > WT_B),2)./sum(reshape(...
            W_best_ABC(:,2,:), nComb, nSim) > WT_B,2);
GAvg_C  = sum(reshape(W_best_ABC(:,3,:), nComb, nSim).*(reshape(...
            W_best_ABC(:,3,:), nComb, nSim) > WT_C),2)./sum(reshape(...
            W_best_ABC(:,3,:), nComb, nSim) > WT_C,2);

f = Cu_A .* GAvg_A + Cu_B .* GAvg_B + Cu_C .* GAvg_C + (nSim./...
        n_b_global) .* c_p + (c_f./n_b_global) + ((nSim - n_b_global)./...
        n_b_global) .* c_l;

Function = f;
```

#### Profiler

This is the [Main Profiler](http://cl.ly/3X3Z1a2k0r1Y/Profiler.pdf) and these are: the [MHW function](http://cl.ly/1S0f3P01381a/Profiler_MHW.pdf) and the [Weight function](http://cl.ly/3X2L0y1f2F2L/Profiler_Weight.pdf). The main problems are in the Weight since it's called 3000times for each GA generation...Above the Weight function code:

#### Weight Function Code

```
function [ HopperWeight UncertainWeight ] = Weight( nComb, H, alpha, AllComb, CellUncertainty )

HopperWeight = randn(nComb,H) * alpha;
HopperWeight = (1+HopperWeight) .* AllComb;
idx = HopperWeight<0;
random = randn(sum(idx(:)), 1);
HopperWeight(idx) = random .* ((1+alpha) .* AllComb(idx));

%ADD ERROR
RandomizeUncertainty = randn(nComb,H) * CellUncertainty;
UncertainWeight = abs((1+RandomizeUncertainty) .* HopperWeight);
end
```

Is there something that I am missing in order to optimize better the Weight function and in general the time consuming part in the MHW function? (If you need the GA launcher in order to try the MHW function use [THIS](http://cl.ly/text/2Y3W211Q0S3G/clear%20close%20all%20clc%20%20%20Define%20R.txt) code)

TIA

Comment: I'm not sure of the "setup problem" is so well known, probably there are uncountable many setup problems. But what I can see from your profiler results is that you spent a lot of time in `sub2ind`. Not sure if your code really needs it. Also the functions are called a lot of time (200,000 times). Maybe some of these calls can be vectorized.

Comment: @Trilarion Who knows the MHW machine knows very well the setup problem :). Yess, `sub2ind` is very time consuming but I don't know how replace it with something better (I made a sub2ind without some "error checks" but the result is the same). I've already turn on the vectorized option in GA.